# Why didn't `accumulate` make it into Ranges for C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

I suspect that `accumulate` isn't the only algorithm that didn't make it.

Maybe now there's a better way to perform accumulation (folding) over a range and therefore the `accumulate` is obsolete?

Comment: What do you mean by (folding) as a better way to perform accumulation? Can you give an example?

Comment: There is no `reduce` at the yet either, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894415/why-is-there-still-no-range-enabled-reduction-algorithm-in-std

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, `accumulate` is a perfectly reasonable algorithm, and it's not made obsolete by any other algorithm. The reason for it not being included in C++20 is simply a matter of time. It was considered better to add as much as possible with regards to ranges, without worrying about adding *everything* at once. Otherwise, there was a risk that *none* of the constrained algorithms would have made it to C++20, which would have been a shame.

There are still a few algorithms that haven't been constrained yet, as well as the entirety of the `<numeric>`, and `<memory>` headers.

Fortunately, there is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1813r0.pdf) to add these remaining algorithms (and I'm optimistic that these will be added in C++23). In fact, the introduction to this proposal answers your question nicely:

> “Every time someone asks why we didn’t cover `<numeric>` and `<memory>` algorithms: We thought 187 pages of TS was enough.”
> — Casey Carter

Answer (score 5):

[`std::ranges::fold_left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/fold_left) is the corresponding algorithm, added in C++23. Unfortunately, I don't know of any compiler that already implements it.. However, copying the "possible implementation" from cppreference does work.