# Why is there still no range-enabled reduction algorithm in std?

Tags: c++, range, std, c++23, isocpp

The only options available are `std::ranges::for_each` and simple range-based `for` loop. No counterparts for `std::accumulate`, `std::reduce` or `std::inner_product`. `std::ranges::reduce` would be enough, if it were present; inner product can be achieved combining reduce with zip. Falling back to iterator based algorithms is disappointing. Adapting reduce for personal codebase is not a big deal, but a std function is IMHO a lot more desirable. I am wondering if there is such function in std lib or on the 23 horizons.

Regards,
FM.

Comment: Small note, but an important one: you can still use `std::accumulate()` and `std::reduce()` etc. with ranges. You just have to do `r.begin(), r.end()`.

Comment: Thanks for remark. I knew that. But what's the point if you still need the `begin` & `end` pair? The probability of using unrelated iterators for the pair is a source for bugs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why is there still no range-enabled reduction algorithm in std?

Because they were not included in "The One Ranges Proposal" P0896 for C++20.

> I am wondering if there is such function ... on the 23 horizons.

The expansion of ranges in C++23 has been planned in proposal P2214 "A Plan for C++23 Ranges". The proposal was divided into 3 tiers of priority. Ideally, all tiers would be part of C++23, but that depends on whether there is time for it.

`std::ranges::fold` is a counterpart to `std::accumulate` and it It was planned for top tier and has been proposed in P2322 "ranges::fold".

`std::ranges::reduce` was planned in the middle tier.

`std::inner_product` counterpart was decided to not be included in the plan for C++23 ranges as `fold` and `reduce` were considered sufficient.

> can be achieved combining reduce with zip

Zip views themseleves weren't in the C++20 ranges either. But they were planned in the top tier for C++23 and have been proposed in P2321 "zip".

Comment: and the execution policy?

Comment: There was P0836 "Introduce Parallelism to the Ranges TS" prior to C++20 to use executors from P0443 "A Unified Executors Proposal for C++". I doubt either will be in C++23.

Comment: Not having this defeats the purpose of ranges :(