# Avoiding repetition of .begin() and .end()

Tags: c++

There are a lot of functions in the C++ standard library that take in an iterator pointing to the start of some collection, followed by an iterator pointing to the end of it.  Quite often we want to operate on all the elements in a collection, rather than some subset, so we end up with a lot of repetition of `.begin()` and `.end()`.  Is there a more concise way of writing this in C++?

For example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> i = {1,2,3,4,5};

int sum = std::accumulate(i.begin(), i.end(), 0);
```

It would be nice if we could write something like `std::accumulate(i, 0)` instead.  Is there a way of doing something like this?

Comment: Create a simple template function on your own, delegating to `std::accumulate(...)`? What's bothering you?

Comment: `namespace std::ranges`?

Comment: If you have a recent enough compiler, how about [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges)? Or if it's not new enough, [the range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) that the standard is based on?

Comment: C++20 has [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), so you can much easier represent operations on containers.

Comment: Slightly surprised that there isn't a `ranges` version of `accumulate`. For a lot of algorithms that take a begin-end iterator pair, there's a [constrained algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges) in C++20 that takes a range instead.

Comment: @Nathan Not all at once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933163/why-didnt-accumulate-make-it-into-ranges-for-c20

Comment: Eric Niebler's **Range v3** has an [accumulate_ints](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/example/accumulate_ints.cpp) example.

Answer (score 2):

C++20 introduced [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges).

For older compilers, or for more completeness, you can use [Boost.Range](https://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: Can you give a code example of how it helps here?